# How to Disable Developer tool in Chrome browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable developer tool of browser when my web page is rendering, using client side script.

Comment: That's no duplicate. OP wants to know how to disable devtools (with javascript). Your possible duplicate is about disabling javascript within devtools.

Comment: In Developer tool I Have Disable Console & sources but from application I am still able to get code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this.